How to modify the text of a Text Composable when a Button is clicked when using strings.xml
I am having trouble figuring out how to do what I want here...I want to change the text in a Text Composable when I click a button but I can't get it to work because I don't see how to reference a given Text Composable from within my button's onClick. Specifically what I want to do is write code after the line
var mult: Double = typeMatchups[attackType][defenseType] * typeMatchups[attackType][defenseType2] 
to change the text of the Text commented as "Display result here". I don't get how I can do this since Composables return Unit and not a reference to the created object, and there is also the issue that I cannot use stringResource() inside onClick because that is not a Composable function.. Here is my code, itemList values are omitted to reduce the size of my post a bit, as are the values of typeMatchups which is a 2D array of Doubles.
As for the code of the DropdownList Composable, I got it from this site.
@Composable
fun ContentView() {
    val itemList = listOf<String>(...)
        
    var selectedIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var selectedIndex2 by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    var selectedIndex3 by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val norm = 1.0
    val weak = 0.5
    val strg = 2.0
    val inef = 0.0
    val typeMatchups = arrayOf(...)
    val buttonModifier = Modifier.width(100.dp)

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        //Start of 1st Row
        Row {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.attack_type))
            DropdownList(
                itemList = itemList,
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex,
                modifier = buttonModifier,
                onItemClick = { selectedIndex = it },)
        }
        //End of 1st Row
        //Start of 2nd Row
        Row {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.defending_type_1))
            DropdownList(
                itemList = itemList,
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex2,
                modifier = buttonModifier,
                onItemClick = { selectedIndex2 = it })
        }
        //End of 2nd Row
        //Start of 3rd Row
        Row {
            Text(text = stringResource(R.string.defending_type_2))
            DropdownList(
                itemList = itemList,
                selectedIndex = selectedIndex3,
                modifier = buttonModifier,
                onItemClick = { selectedIndex3 = it })
        }
        //End of 3rd Row

        // Text Composable showing selected types
          Text(
              text = stringResource(
                  R.string.selected_types,
                  itemList[selectedIndex],
                  itemList[selectedIndex2],
                  itemList[selectedIndex3]
              ),
              textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
              modifier = Modifier
                  .padding(3.dp)
                  .fillMaxWidth()
                  .background(Color.LightGray),
          )
        Button(onClick = {
            val attackType = selectedIndex
            val defenseType = selectedIndex2
            val defenseType2 = selectedIndex3

            var mult: Double = typeMatchups[attackType][defenseType] * typeMatchups[attackType][defenseType2]

        }) {

            Text("Filled")
        }*/
        //Display result here
        Text(text = stringResource(R.string.button_default))
    }
}


As it is now, the content of your Text is static, it will always be what your string resource R.string.button_default contains.
If you want this to change during runtime you have to define a mutable state for the Texts content, like this:
var text by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
...
Text(text = text)

In between (where the "..." are) you can place your Button. In its onClick callback you can now set the content of the Text to anything you like, e.g. this:
text = mult.toString()

For more, please read this guide: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/state
